# Collapse by tag name instead of indentation

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to edit an xml file containing the following repeated structure:

```
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>[Item's name goes here]</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <string>[multi-line SQL statement goes here]</string>
    </value>
  </item>
```

I'd like to collapse everything but the `<string>` inside the `<key>`. So essentially I just want to collapse every `<value>` tag inside the document. Is there a way to do this?

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> collapses the `<string>` inside the `<value>`, but leaves the one inside the `<key>` alone as it's only one line, so nothing to collapse. It still leaves the following three lines though, that *could* be just the one:

```
    <value>
      <string>
    </value>
```

... fine, but if it's possible I'd love to get it down to 6 lines per item instead of 8...

Answer (score 1):

“I'd like to collapse everything but the `<string>` inside the `<key>`.” If you don’t want to change structure of your document and still make a list of certain nodes you can use XPath. 
N++ has a nice PluginManager available. It used to be part of previous versions of N++ but now it needs be downloaded from ‘https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases/tag/v1.4.9’.
A plugin that allows working with xml files is called ‘XML Tools’.
Once installed choose from the menu Plugins → XML Tools → Evaluate XPath Expression.
There you can specify which content you want to extract from the file.
[image]
[image]